# GCP | VertexAI | JupyterLab Kernel - Connecting State

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am running a user-managed JupyterLab notebook in the Google Cloud Platform environment. Initially, I could successfully execute the code with the expected outputs, without any hassles. However, recently I started facing Kernel issues. It is in a 'Connecting' state forever and throws a Kernel Disconnected error after a few hours. I am unable to perform a simple print/math operation.

[image]

As a workaround, I tried reset/restarting the instance but the issue still persists. I looked for idle-timeout settings if that's the culprit, but it is unavailable on a user-managed notebook.

[image]

If anyone has come across such issues on the JupyterLab notebook in the GCP environment, your inputs are valuable.

Comment: It seems like there might be duplicate library names and that might be conflicting with the startup script. Have you installed any packages recently?