# Jupyter Lab Kernel Connection Problems on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I am trying to transcript some audios using GCP. I have created a project and now I am using the following code in jupyter lab. The bucket with the folder with the audios is also created. When i run the code in the last step it shows **Kernel status: connecting** and and after a while, the kernel dies or is still tries to connect.

Sometimes it also shows the following errror: **Server Connection Error** *A connection to the Jupyter server could not be established. JupyterLab will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or Jupyter server configuration.*

I have tried already to restart de kernel and jupyter and it still doesnt work.

```
# Libraries
#---------------------------------------------------------#
# Data processing libraries
import json

# Transcription library
import whisper

# Environment libraries
import tqdm
import os

# Google Cloud libraries
from google.cloud import storage
import gcsfs

#=========================================================#
# Constants
ID_PROYECTO = 'example'  # Project ID
NOMBRE_BUCKET = 'example-transcript'  # Bucket Name
CARPETA_AUDIOS = 'audios/'  # Audio Folder
CARPETA_TRANSCRIPCIONES = '01. Transcripciones/'  # Transcriptions Folder
IDIOMA = 'es'  # None for autodetect, 'es' for Spanish, other language codes can be checked at https://github.com/openai/whisper/blob/main/whisper/tokenizer.py

# functions to work with buckets
def download_from_gcs(
       client, 
       bucket_name, 
       remote_path, 
       local_path
       ):
   bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
   blob = bucket.blob(remote_path)
   blob.download_to_filename(local_path)

def save_to_gcs(
       client, 
       bucket_name, 
       content, 
       remote_path, 
       content_type = None
       ):
   bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
   blob = bucket.blob(remote_path)
   blob.upload_from_string(content, content_type=content_type)

# function for transcription
def transcription(
       path: str = CARPETA_AUDIOS, 
       project_id: str = ID_PROYECTO,
       bucket_name: str = NOMBRE_BUCKET,
       exit_path: str = CARPETA_TRANSCRIPCIONES,
       extension: list = ['mp3', 'wav', 'WAV'],
       model: str = 'large', 
       extract: str = 'all',
       verbose: bool = True,
       language: str = IDIOMA,
       ):
   model = whisper.load_model(model)
   
   #extension = ['mp3', 'wav', 'WAV']
   
   client = storage.Client(project = project_id)
   fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project = project_id)
   all_files = fs.ls(f"{bucket_name}/{path}")
   
   audios = [f for f in all_files if f.split('.')[-1] in extension]

   for i in tqdm.tqdm(audios, disable = verbose is False):
       local_audio_path = os.path.join('/tmp', os.path.basename(i))
       remote_path = i[len(bucket_name)+1:]
       download_from_gcs(client, bucket_name, remote_path, local_audio_path)
       transcript = model.transcribe(
           local_audio_path, 
           language = language
           )
       
       if extract == 'all':
           json_content = json.dumps(transcript)
           json_remote_path = os.path.join(
               exit_path, 
               remote_path+'.json'
               )
           save_to_gcs(
               client,
               bucket_name, 
               json_content, 
               json_remote_path, 
               content_type = 'application/json'
               )

# Function call
transcription()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on your issue by giving more details about your jupyterlab configuration. Are you running the jupyter lab on your local machine or gcp? Can you tell whether you are using the vertex ai, datproc support lab?

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde I am running jupyter lab from GCP. I created a project using vertex ai workbench and i clicked in "open jupyter". I also created first a terminal where i created a new environment in Python 3.9, and then i install ipykernel...

Comment: Hi @nils, Have you installed any packages recently? If so, it might be causing the kernel [connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75982887/gcp-vertexai-jupyterlab-kernel-connecting-state) issue. Could you follow this Troubleshooting Vertex AI Workbench [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/troubleshooting-workbench)?